# Unresolved External Symbol in QT connect()

Tags: c++, qt

I´m pretty new to QT and C++ and I´m getting this error that I can´t manage to solve. I´m trying to connect the currentRowChanged() signal of the TableView selection model to a slot I created so I can get data from the row that is selected.

This is my code: 
**Opciones.cpp**

```
    #include "opciones.h"
    #include "ui_opciones.h"
    #include <qsqldatabase.h>
    #include <qsqlquery.h>
    #include <qdebug.h>
    #include <qmessagebox.h>
    #include <qsqltablemodel.h>
    #include <qitemselectionmodel.h>
    #include "QModelIndex"

    Opciones::Opciones(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Opciones)
    {
       ....   
        connect(ui->tablaJuegos->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous)),
            this,SLOT(filaSeleccionada(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous)));
    db.close();



}

Opciones::~Opciones()
{
    delete ui;
}
void filaSeleccionada(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous){


}
```

**Opciones.h**

```
#ifndef OPCIONES_H
#define OPCIONES_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QModelIndex>


namespace Ui {
class Opciones;
}

class Opciones : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Opciones(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Opciones();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();


public slots:
    void filaSeleccionada(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous);



private:
    Ui::Opciones *ui;
};

#endif // OPCIONES_H
```

I´m having problems with the connect() function which is giving me the following error:

```
moc_opciones.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Opciones::filaSeleccionada(class QModelIndex const &,class QModelIndex const &)" (?filaSeleccionada@Opciones@@QEAAXAEBVQModelIndex@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl Opciones::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@Opciones@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

the variable tablaJuegos is a TableView I created in the UI designer of QT.Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Opciones.cpp you haven't declared filaSeleccionada to be scoped within the Opciones class.  Declare it this way:

```
void Opciones::filaSeleccionada(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous){
}
```

What you've done in your code is to declare a new free function, filaSeleccionada.  The compiler has no problem with this, as it is fine to have both a free function and a class-scoped method with the same name.  Moreover, at link time there is still not an error, since you are not calling Opciones::filaSeleccionada *directly* from anywhere.  Therefore, the problem is first encountered by connect().

Comment: That was a noob error...  haha! Thanks alot. The error is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Another error you have in your code besides the one mentioned by Derek Jones in his answer, is that when you connect signals to slots in Qt, you don't pass parameter names in the signatures. You also don't have to include the const references explicitly.

In your code you have:

```
connect(ui->tablaJuegos->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous)),
        this,SLOT(filaSeleccionada(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous)));
```

What you should have is:

```
connect(ui->tablaJuegos->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)),
        this,SLOT(filaSeleccionada(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)));
```